# Explanation about the proplem

Tags: complex-analysis

Problem:
Argue geometrically that $|z-4 i|+ |z+ 4 i|=10$ is an *ellipse*, and then show this algebraically.

Comment: Welcome. You will want to quickly click edit on your question and add context to your post. Include brief information about how you arrived at this problem, and especially what you have tried. Definitely read [how to ask](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529502/explanation-about-the-proplem). This brief context makes the difference between many great responses, and..., well..., you may or may not see see.

Answer (score 4):

An ellipse is the locus of points such that the sum of the distances to a pair of specified foci is a specified constant.

Now, $|z-4i|$ is the distance from $z$ to $4i$, etc. So this is the equation of the locus of points that are at total distance $10$ from the pair of points $\pm4i$.

Algebraically, you can make the substitution $z=y+ix$ and simplify. You will get it the form of the standard equation for the ellipse.